# CSS place href title under image in UL list

Tags: html, css, image

I am using [this](http://valhead.com/2011/08/04/polaroid-gallery/) polaroid gallery css effect. I have done some modifications, and would like to add title from the href as the image title under the main image. At this point I am only able to add this title on the right side of the < li>. I would like to have it underneath. This is the code I am using to fetch the title:

```
 #gallery li a:after {
  bottom: 0; 
  content: attr(title);
}
```

Se my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bd74obbm/) for more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `display: block` in styles like below:

```
#gallery li a:after {
  content: attr(title);
  display: block;
}
```

It will make `:after` pseudo element to behave like a block level element and block level elements always start from a new line by default.

Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bd74obbm/4/):

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: block` in the `#gallery li a:after`.

```
#gallery li a:after {
  bottom: 0;
  content: attr(title);  
  display: block
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the element's position to `position: absolute`.

So the final bit of code would look something like this:

```
#gallery li a:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  content: attr(title);
}
```

The result then looks like this:
[image]

You can of course play with the position any way you want.